# How to issue notification/alert from JavaScript when application in background - PhoneGap iPhone/iOS

Tags: javascript, iphone, objective-c, ios, cordova

I want to issue a notification/alert to the user - based on a timed event emanating from a stop watch. The logic is in JavaScript, the application runs in PhoneGap on iPhone.

Problem: iPhone pauses JavaScript execution in the webview on iPhone/iOs when the application is in the background.

Triggering a native alert dialogs, using e.g. PhoneGap's navigator.notification.alert(), fails because the alert is simply not invoked while in the background.

How can I efficiently combine this with, e.g., UILocalNotification? - Any examples / samples / plugins available?

Answer (score 0):

In general, iOS doesn't allow long-running background tasks, unless you're doing background audio, location services, or VOIP.

You could use Task Completion (beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler) to keep your logic running for a little while once you app goes into the background. However iOS will still terminate your task after about 10 minutes.

Another option is to pre-schedule all your timed events using UILocalNotification. You can schedule as many as 128 events, each with an optional repeat interval. Here's the sample code from Apple's documentation:

```
// Create a new notification.
UILocalNotification* alarm = [[[UILocalNotification alloc] init] autorelease];
if (alarm)
{
    alarm.fireDate = theDate;
    alarm.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
    alarm.repeatInterval = 0;
    alarm.soundName = @"alarmsound.caf";
    alarm.alertBody = @"Time to wake up!";

    [app scheduleLocalNotification:alarm];
}
```

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html